# So I have this question my friend asked me, but I can't seem to quite get it.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A class of 24 students and 2 teachers were on a cinema trip. In the cinema 6 of the students had seats next to each other. In how many different ways could they sit next to each other?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What is ''they'' signify here?

Comment: If ''they'' signifies students then the answer is $18! \times 6.$

Comment: They signify the students.

Comment: is it 6*5*4*3*2*1 = 720 because there being six seats and six students that can take any seat?

Comment: Yes $6! = 720$ is the number of ways those particular six students could sit in a row of 6 seats. But then why bring up the other eighteen students and the teachers?